# Kotlin Iterable not supported in Apache Beam?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Apache beam seems to be refusing to recognise Kotlin's `Iterable`.  Here is a sample code:

```
@ProcessElement
fun processElement(
    @Element input: KV<String, Iterable<String>>, receiver: OutputReceiver<String>
) {
    val output = input.key + "|" + input.value.toString()
    println("output: $output")
    receiver.output(output)
}
```

I get the following weird error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
   ...PrintString, @ProcessElement processElement(KV, OutputReceiver), @ProcessElement processElement(KV, OutputReceiver):
   @Element argument must have type org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String, java.lang.Iterable<? extends java.lang.String>>
```

Sure enough, if I replace `Iterable` with `java.lang.Iterable`, the same code works just fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Version of depedencies:

- kotlin-jvm: `1.3.21`
- org.apache.beam: `2.11.0`

Here is a gist with full codes and stack trace:

- https://gist.github.com/marcoslin/e1e19afdbacac9757f6974592cfd8d7f#file-apache-beam-iterable-notworking-kt

**Update**:

After a bit of trial and error, I found out that while `List<String>` throws similar exception but `MutableList<String>` actually works:

```
class PrintString: DoFn<KV<String, MutableList<String>>, String>() {
    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(
        @Element input: KV<String, MutableList<String>>, receiver: OutputReceiver<String>
    ) {
        val output = input.key + "|" + input.value.toString()
        println("output: $output")
        receiver.output(output)
    }
}
```

So, this reminded me that Kotlin's Immutable collection are actually only interface and that underlying collection is still mutable.  However, attempt to replace `Iterable` with `MutableIterable` continue to raise the error.

**Update 2**:

I deployed my Kotlin Dataflow job using the `MutableList` per above and job failed with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn$WindowReiterable cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:184)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
```

I had to switch back to use `java.lang.Iterable`.

Comment: Is this at runtime or at compile time? Can you share more of the stack trace?

Comment: @mkobit stack trace added to https://gist.github.com/marcoslin/e1e19afdbacac9757f6974592cfd8d7f#file-stack-trace-txt.  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, when using a `ParDo` following a `GroupByKey`. It turns out that a `@JvmWildcard` annotation is needed in the `Iterable` generic type when writing a transformation that accepts the result of a `GroupByKey`.

See the contrived example below that reads a file and groups by the first character of each line.

```java
class BeamPipe {
  class ConcatLines : DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<@JvmWildcard String>>, KV<String, String>>() {
    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(@Element input: KV<String, Iterable<@JvmWildcard String>>, receiver: OutputReceiver<KV<String, String>>) {
      receiver.output(KV.of(input.key, input.value.joinToString("\n")))
    }
  }

  fun pipe(options: PipelineOptions) {
    val file =
        "testFile.txt"
    val p = Pipeline.create(options)
    p.apply(TextIO.read().from(file))
        .apply("Key lines by first character",
            WithKeys.of { line: String -> line[0].toString() }
                .withKeyType(TypeDescriptors.strings()))
        .apply("Group lines by first character", GroupByKey.create<String, String>())
        .apply("Concatenate lines", ParDo.of(ConcatLines()))
        .apply("Write to files", FileIO.writeDynamic<String, KV<String, String>>()
            .by { it.key }
            .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
            .via(Contextful.fn(ProcessFunction { it.value }), TextIO.sink())
            .to("whatever")
            .withNaming { key -> FileIO.Write.defaultNaming(key, ".txt") }
        )
    p.run()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in the Beam Kotlin SDK. The Reflection analysis for your `@ProcessElement` method does not work correctly. You can probably work around this by using `ProcessContext ctx` instead of using the `@Element` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @mxm. I tried that but still getting the same `IllegalArgumentException`.  Added sample code and stacktrace to gist above.  Similar to the other example, `MutableList` works just fine.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the update! We will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with kotlin but it seems that you need to import `import java.lang.Iterable` before using it in your code.

Comment: thanks but per my question, if I do the import it does work.  That shouldn't be needed with Kotlin as `Iterable` is equivalent to `java.lang.Iterable`.  This problem manifest itself in other area as well.  For example, when using `GroupByKey` that returns a `Iterable` (which I cannot set), it raises the same error when combined with `ParDo`.

Answer (score 0):

May I know how to fix the issue when we get the iterable from groupbykey.create(). i could not groupbykey as you did  javalang iterable

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: @HardWorker you should ask a question with some sample code where other can easily run.  I can try to help further with more info.

Comment: @HardWorker Just noticed you are experiencing similar problem. My answer above might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

For those are experiencing this issue and found their way here, my current workaround to keep writing the pipeline in kotlin is to create a Java static class with function(s) that creates, contains, and processes your Iterable(s). The result (in non-iterable format) can then be passed back to the kotlin.